# What VBA event is triggered when closing a form?

Tags: ms-access

If I don't fill out all the required fields in my form, I get an ugly error when I click the "x" in the upper right corner.
I would like to override the default error with a custom error message, but I can't figure out which VBA event to associate this code with. the Form_Close event doesn't seem to work when I put an error handler in there.

Access 2010

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Err_Unload          ' Initialize error handling.
    'insert routine
Exit_Unload:                      ' Label to resume after error.
    Exit Sub                      ' Exit before error handler.
Err_Unload:                       ' Label to jump to on error.
    'MsgBox Err & " " & Error$    ' Place error handling here.
    Resume Exit_Unload
End Subenter code here
```

Still receiving errors even while using this code.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
On Error GoTo Err_Unload          ' Initialize error handling.
    ' Code to do something here.
Exit_Unload:                          ' Label to resume after error.
    Exit Sub                  ' Exit before error handler.
Err_Unload:                           ' Label to jump to on error.
    'MsgBox Err & " " & Error$           ' Place error handling here.
    Resume Exit_Unload
End Sub
```

Comment: If you do not fill in required fields and try to close the form, the ugly error message will appear before any form events are triggered (confirmed in 2007). In order to avoid this, you will need to set up default values for your required fields or determine them using the On Current event. Just make sure you check the record in the before update event to be sure the input values are acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you attempt to close a form which has unsaved changes to the form's current record, Access will first attempt to commit those changes.  You can't intercept that action from `Form_Unload` or `Form_Close`.

BTW, although you didn't mention it, I would expect you to see the same thing when navigating to a different record if the record you're navigating away from includes unsaved changes with missing values for required fields.

In the case where your form's record source includes a table with an autonumber field, use the form's before update event to check whether required values are present.  If there is no autonumber field involved, consider doing the checking from both the form's before insert and before update events.

However if the whole point of this is to get a friendlier message for a missing value in a required field, see whether changing the table's properties is satisfactory.  For example, you could set `Required` to `No`, then use `Is Not Null` for the field's `Validation Rule` which would allow you to assign your friendly text message as the field's `Validation Text` property.

[image: Table design Required and Validation properties]

Answer (score 3):

From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/order-of-events-for-database-objects-HP005186761.aspx,

> Similarly, when you close a form, the following sequence of events
>   occurs:
>
> Exit (control) → LostFocus (control) → Unload (form) → Deactivate
>   (form) → Close (form)
>
> If you've changed data in a control, the BeforeUpdate and AfterUpdate
>   events for both the control and the form occur before the Exit event
>   for the control.

What's likely causing your error is the BeforeUpdate event when the form tries to save your changes, but fails because you haven't filled in required fields.  You can create some validation code and run it in the BeforeUpdate event for the form to make sure everything is OK and send the appropriate message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to use:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)

End Sub
```

Comment: I am still getting an error that says "You must enter a value in the 'tblOrder.OrderID' field. I placed my code in the question above.

Comment: What are you doing? Data entry? It sounds as if you have a required field and you are initializing a record. An undo may work for you or you may like to look at the Form error event, this will trap validation and key field error and such like. You may also like ask if the user would like to complete the record or exit.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a form event called `On Error`, which has two arguments: what the error is and what response Access should perform.